# Asset path, fingerprints and thumbnail switcher

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very inexperienced with RoR but just inherited a project to finish.

We have a jQuery function attached to some thumbnail image 'click' event that swaps out a larger image. Because of teh asset path fingerprinting feature, this isn't working. The approach in use in the javascript function is simply to get the large image URL by removing a substring from the thumbnail filename (src attribute). Since the fingerprint hashes are different from the thumb to the large file, this doesn't work.

What's the best approach to solve such a problem?

```
    $('.thumb').click(function () {
        var thumbUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var bigUrl = thumbUrl.replace('_tile', '');
```

Here's the javascript...there's no real 'code', just that the precompiled assets for this controller/view have fingerprint hashes in the filenames, and the large file fingerprint is different from the thumb file fingerprint (naturally) and so the string replacement in the image swap function doesn't work.

Comment: Hey Jcorry, do you think you could provide some code to go along with your description? It would make it less abstract to talk about and more easily understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you add the large image url to the img tag as a data attribute when you render the HTML, then you can pull that out in the javascript function, e.g.:

In your ERB template:

```
<%= image_tag(
  "thumb.jpg",
  :data => { "large_image_url" => image_url("large.jpg") }
) %>
```

Then, in your JS:

```
$('.thumb').click(function () {
  var bigURL = $(this).data("large_image_url");
  ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is perfect. The image_url() function was what I was looking for.

Comment: Except that I am compiling on my local machine and then using wget to generate all of these static HTML files. THOSE get FTPd to the server. image_url() is putting the localhost:3000 in the image URLs, so it only works on my machine. How do you make it use root relative URLs for resources?

Answer (score 1):

You could stash the various expected URLs in data attributes in the `thumb` div, or wherever it would be most relevant.  Like so:

```
<div class='thumb' 
     data-large-size='http://server/path/large.jpg'
     data-small-size='http://server/path/small.jpg'>
   ...
</div>
```

Then just grab them in jQuery:

```
$('.thumb').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).data('large-size');
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', url);
}
```

No need to calculate anything.  The urls can be supplied by the [asset URL helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb).